# Symfony 1.4 style form field with errors

Tags: php, validation, symfony-1.4

I want to change the background color of my field when an error occurs.

In Java Struts, I can do something like this:

```
<s:textfield name="parameter" cssClass="normal_css_class" cssErrorClass="class_on_error" cssErrorStyle="style_on error"/>
```

I want to be able to perform something like above. The tag renders the field cssErrorClass when the field parameter has errors. No more additional Javascript is required.

Currently I have the following (very dirty) code in my template:

```
<?php if($form['bill_to']->hasError()): ?>
  <?php echo $form['bill_to']->render(array('style' => 'background-color: red')) ?>
<?php else: ?>
  <?php echo $form['bill_to']->render() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php echo $form['bill_to']->renderError() ?>
```

The above code works but is there a way to implement it so that I just have to call:

```
<?php echo $form['bill_to']->render() ?>
```

and it will then perform the setting of the styles? I'm thinking of overriding the render() method but I am not sure if it is the right approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatter class like this:

```
class sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatterCustom extends sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatter
{
    protected
        $rowFormat                  = "<div class=\"%row_class%\">%label% %field% %hidden_fields% %help%</div>",
        $helpFormat                 = "%help%",
        $errorRowFormat             = "",
        $errorListFormatInARow      = "\n%errors%\n",
        $errorRowFormatInARow       = "<span class=\"error\">%error%</span>\n",
        $namedErrorRowFormatInARow  = "%error%\n",
        $decoratorFormat            = "%content%";


    public function formatRow($label, $field, $errors = array(), $help = '', $hiddenFields = null)
    {
        $row = parent::formatRow(
            $label,
            $field,
            $errors,
            $help,
            $hiddenFields
        );

        return strtr($row, array(
            '%row_class%' => (count($errors) > 0) ? ' error' : '',
        ));
    }
}// decorator class
```

and apply it to a form inside it's configure() method like this:

```
class myForm extends sfForm
{
    public function configure()
    {
        // ....


        $formatter = new sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatterCustom($this->widgetSchema);
        $this->widgetSchema->addFormFormatter('custom', $formatter);
        $this->widgetSchema->setFormFormatterName('custom');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into form formatters, see http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatter.

A formformatter object can be obtained with `$this->getWidgetSchema()->getFormFormatter()` when you are in the configure method of your sfForm.